# getting error "ImportError: No module named ccg" in importing a python custom module into a python script

Tags: python, import, module, importerror

I have imported a custom module into a python script. But it is giving me the below error:-

ImportError: No module named ccg

Anyone can help me out of it here please ?

Comment: Please provide more info.. as in what is the directory structure, from where are you running the import etc

Comment: we have an internal tool name ccg which I have installed on my linux VM under path :~/ccg/bin as PATH variable and I am exporting it as "export PATH=~/ccm/bin:/home/rahul/tools/anaconda3/bin:~/tools/cmake/bin:~/perl/perl/bin:~/apache-ant/bin:${PATH}"

Now, I have a script name "python_Test_Script" on path "/home/rahul/testrepo" . And I am importing that ccg  module into this script.

But while execution, I am getting error "ImportError: No module named ccg"

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux PATH has nothing to do with Python's path. That is, just because the directory the module is in is part of PATH, that does not mean Python will automatically find it. Python searches specific directories, regardless of whether they are in your PATH or not. To find Python's path you can create and execute a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This will tell where Python looks for modules. Either put the module there or append the directory where is resides to Python's search path.